# Powershell add-adgroupmember from variable with multiple values.

Tags: list, powershell, sharepoint

Background.
Powershell command pulling Sharepoint List distro data from a multichoice column.

```
    $EmailDistro=  ($listitem.Fields["Email Distribution List Membership"]).getfieldvalueastext($listitem["Email Distribution List Membership"])

    $EmailDistros = Distro1,Distro2,Distro3
```

Command I would like to run.

```
   "$emaildistros" | add-adgroupmember -member jdoe
```

Unfortunately this translates to

```
    Distro1,Distro2,Distro3 | add-adgroupmember -member jdoe
```

but I need it like this.

```
  "Distro1","Distro2","Distro3" | Add-adgroupmemeber -member jdoe
```

I am open to workarounds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the result your getting back from Sharepoint is a string containing all the groups and not an array.  Split the result you get back into an explicit array:

```
$EmailDistros = $EmailDistros -split ","
```

Then you can pipe the array like you'd expect:

```
$EmailDistros | Add-ADGroupMember -member jdoe
```

You could also do more with each distro:

```
$EmailDistros | % { Add-ADGroupMember -member jdoe }
```

Comment: Awesome. thanks! I saw it was a single object but didn't know how to split it out.